Chrome says SSL is not secure Invalid, but certificate is valid
I’ve developed a small frontend using Streamlit and deployed it on an EC2 instance. I’ve also set up a wildcard certificate for the domain, using the same URL as the domain name. Despite my efforts, I’ve been unable to resolve an issue for over two days. I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this problem.



A wildcard certificate can't be "the same domain as the domain name". A wildcard always represents the domain name, plus a subdomain. Your domain name is ad5mo-test.com. The wildcard certificate only matches *.ad5mo-test.com. So the wildcard certificate would match subdomains like www.ad5mo-test.com, test.ad5mo-test.com, production.ad5mo-test.com, etc. But it does not match the root domain of ad5mo-test.com
You need to create a new certificate that either just has ad5mo-test.com as the domain, or it has both ad5mo-test.com and *.ad5mo-test.com as alternate names.

Thank you so much. I added subdomain in the Hosted Zones with type CNAME & value as DNS name it worked it worked.
